# Aurelia popup when refreshing the page not working

Tags: onbeforeunload, aurelia

As we know, we can put a pop up asking if we are sure about refreshing the page when we click the refresh button on the browser. Usually it is done by adding an event listener on onbeforeunload.

However, in my Aurelia application, I try to do that but it's not working.

let's say this is my app.js ( root ModelView )

```
export class App {

this.refreshClicked = () =>{ return "Are you sure you want to exit?"; };

attached(){
window.addEventListener("onbeforeunload", this.refreshClicked);
}
```

But it is not working, however, if we replace the return statement to `console.log("clicked")` I can see that the listener works without any problem.

Any help?

Comment: You need to add a `confirm` method around your string. `return confirm("Are you sure you want to exit?")` Right now you're just returning a string.

Comment: @JessedeBruijne yeah I realized that, thank you.

Comment: have you tried using the canDeactivate() callback?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you are adding event handler through `window.addEventListener`, you don't use `on` prefix in that case. So it's either:

```js
attached() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.refreshClicked);
}
```

or an older, not recommended, syntax:

```js
attached() {
    window.onbeforeunload(this.refreshClicked);
}
```

Second, you'll need to set the `returnValue` property on `Event` object and also return the same string value to support more browsers. To learn more about this event (and various browser quirks), check out [its MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload).

Your `refreshClicked` should look like this:

```js
this.refreshClicked = e => {
    const confirmation = 'Are you sure you want to exit?';
    e.returnValue = confirmation;
    return confirmation;
};
```

Comment: Ok quick modification to my previous comment. Now it works well, but it seems that I need to click anywhere on my application windows before clicking on refresh button in the browser in order that we detect the refresh. Is there a way to detect a refresh if I don't click on my application ? I mean just open the app then click refresh without clicking anywhere in my app windows..

Comment: And btw the message is not shown, I always get :This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved.:

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload 

1st question:
> Note: To combat unwanted pop-ups, browsers may not display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with, or may even not display them at all.

2nd question:
> Some browsers display the returned string in the dialog box, but others display their own message.

You can see custom message support under browser compatibility on that page.